# How to set a restriction on input type="text"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-input

I have an input `type="text"` `pattern="[0-9]{10}"` to input 10-digit telephone numbers (I don't want to use `type="tel"` for some reason.) Also I really need one more restriction that users are NOT allowed to enter a telephone number starting with "0". Can I do that? Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the "tel" type?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `type="tel"`?

Comment: What about `pattern="[1-9][0-9]{9}"`?

Comment: Regex could be one way to do that.